# Mousing over one div pushes another one down way too far

Tags: css, html, css-float, positioning

I was making a website just for fun to iron up my skills, and I made some animated mouse-over divs. All of them work fine when moused over, but the top left one seems to push down the one right below it.

Here are some pictures and my code:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/39/werwe1.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/werwe2.png/

And my code:

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
font: bold 20px Prisoner SF
}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
   display: block;
}

#big_wrapper{
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 20px 0px;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}

body{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;

} 

#main_div{
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}

#main_section{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, border 2s, scale 2s,
}

#sidebar {
width: 500px;

}

.subsection1{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, border 2s, scale 2s,
}

.subsection2{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, border 2s, scale 2s,
}

.subsection3{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, border 2s, scale 2s,
}

.subsection4{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, border 2s, scale 2s,
}

#main_section:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.subsection1:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.subsection2:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.subsection3:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.subsection4:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

/* End Section Code */

/* Footer Code */

#footer{
text-align: center;
}

/* End Footer Code */
```

Comment: Set up a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so that we can see the issues directly.

Comment: Ok, it should be up in a few minutes.

Comment: Here it is, mouse over the "PDA-4000" tab. http://jsfiddle.net/A44WA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why it's happening is b/c when you hover over the top left one, you scale it by 5%

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
```

and since you got all those boxes floating, when you scale the one on the top left, it over crowds the width of the one at the bottom, so it jumps below the bottom right box.

in mathematical terms, the boxes are contained within `.sidebar` which has no height set up so it simply adopts the same height of `.main_div` = 450px. if you do the math you'll see that if you scale the top left box by 5% ((200+10)*1.05 = 210) and add it to the bottom (then you will have to add the paddings and margins as well), you will see that the total will be more than 450px, and so the jumping happens.

to prove what i'm saying you can try reducing the height of the top left to say, 150px (rather than 200px) and you'll see that hovering over it no longer bumps the one below to the bottom.

in short, floated elements must fit in the containing div. if they don't, they start jumping around

**update:**

upon further research.. it turns out the problem isn't the fact that the heights of the boxes became larger than the container as i claimed earlier.. rather it's simply because you are using different heights for your floated elements.. floating elements don't work well if they are of varying heights. (you will see a detailed example exactly like yours in p. 211 in [css the missing manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449325947).

to prove my point.. do the following to debug what's going on:

1. on chrome right click the window and go to `inspect element`
2. go to the div `.subsection1` and change it's height to 210px

   - you will see that the box below it goes down, which reproduces your problem
3. now change the height of `.subsection2` to 210px as well..

   - you will see that the box that went down goes back to its original position..
4. if you change the heights of `.subsection3` and `.subsection4` you'll notice that nothing changes (ie no box goes down etc)

   - this proves the point that having elements with varying heights floating causes unpredictable, or *undefined* behaviour.. so it's a situation that should just be avoided

**final note:**

learning css by trial and error like you are doing is good.. but i strongly recommend that you follow a structured book (like the one i linked to).. css can be very unintuitive and frustrating, and you can easily build wrong conclusions based on your trial and error findings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix it with your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I set the sidebar to 600px and put a red border around it. The border goes to the white footer line so I don't understand how the divs do not fit inside the sidebar div. Could you explain a bit more please? Thanks.

Comment: hey man my initial answer wasn't entirely correct.. i made an update.. hopefully it's worth a vote up ;)

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll try to debug it and I'll look into the book that you told me about. :) Can't really upvote because I need 15 rep but I accepted your answer.

Comment: much appreciated man.. and welcome to stack over flow.. your second home :)